# php setting up profile for account type

Tags: php, mysqli

hey guys need some help or advice, im building a member based website and looking for a way to point the logged in user to their profile which is based on their account type.

the system started with 1 account and evereything runs fine, i have added the accounts field into mysql and the registration form lets them pick the account they need i just need a push in the right direction to point them to their profile at login

heres my current code that directs them on login

```
<?php
/* 
* Date: january 20, 2012
   *------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
session_start(); // Start Session First Thing
// Force script errors and warnings to show on page in case php.ini file is set to not display them
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; // Connect to the database
$dyn_www = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // Dynamic www.domainName available now to you in all of your scripts that include this file
//------ CHECK IF THE USER IS LOGGED IN OR NOT AND GIVE APPROPRIATE OUTPUT -------
$logOptions = ''; // Initialize the logOptions variable that gets printed to the page
// If the session variable and cookie variable are not set this code runs
if (!isset($_SESSION['idx'])) { 
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['idCookie'])) {
     $logOptions = '<a href="//' . $dyn_www . '/register.php">Register Account</a>
 &nbsp;&nbsp; | &nbsp;&nbsp; 
 <a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/login.php">Log In</a>';
   }
}
// If session ID is set for logged in user without cookies remember me feature set
if (isset($_SESSION['idx'])) { 

$decryptedID = base64_decode($_SESSION['idx']);
$id_array = explode("p3h9xfn8sq03hs2234", $decryptedID);
$logOptions_id = $id_array[1];
$logOptions_username = $_SESSION['username'];
$logOptions_username = substr('' . $logOptions_username . '', 0, 15); // cut user name down in length if too long

// Check if this user has any new PMs and construct which envelope to show
$sql_pm_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id='$logOptions_id' AND opened='0' LIMIT 1");
$num_new_pm = mysql_num_rows($sql_pm_check);
if ($num_new_pm > 0) {
    $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="images/pm2.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
} else {
    $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="images/pm1.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
}
// Ready the output for this logged in user
$logOptions = $PM_envelope . ' &nbsp; &nbsp;
<a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '">Home</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/profile.php?id=' . $logOptions_id . '">Profile</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="dc">
<a href="#" onclick="return false">Account &nbsp; <img src="images/darr.gif" width="10" height="5" alt="Account Options" border="0"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/edit_profile.php">Account Options</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_inbox.php">Inbox Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_sentbox.php">Sent Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
';

} else if (isset($_COOKIE['idCookie'])) {// If id cookie is set, but no session ID is set yet, we set it below and update stuff

$decryptedID = base64_decode($_COOKIE['idCookie']);
$id_array = explode("nm2c0c4y3dn3727553", $decryptedID);
$userID = $id_array[1]; 
$userPass = $_COOKIE['passCookie'];
// Get their user first name to set into session var
  $sql_uname = mysql_query("SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM memberstable WHERE id='$userID' AND password='$userPass' LIMIT 1");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql_uname);
if ($numRows == 0) {
    // Kill their cookies and send them back to homepage if they have cookie set but are not a member any longer
    setcookie("idCookie", '', time()-42000, '/');
    setcookie("passCookie", '', time()-42000, '/');
    header("location: index.php"); // << makes the script send them to any page we set
    exit();
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_uname)){ 
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $surname = $row["lastname"];
    $useremail = $row["email"];
}

$_SESSION['id'] = $userID; // now add the value we need to the session variable
$_SESSION['idx'] = base64_encode("g4p3h9xfn8sq03hs2234$userID");
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_SESSION['surname'] = $surname;
$_SESSION['useremail'] = $useremail;
$_SESSION['userpass'] = $userPass;

$logOptions_id = $userID;
$logOptions_uname = $firstname;
$logOptions_uname = $surname;
$logOptions_uname = substr('' . $logOptions_uname . '', 0, 15); 
///////////          Update Last Login Date Field       /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
mysql_query("UPDATE memberstable SET last_log_in=now() WHERE id='$logOptions_id'"); 
// Ready the output for this logged in user
// Check if this user has any new PMs and construct which envelope to show
$sql_pm_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM private_messages WHERE to_id='$logOptions_id' AND opened='0' LIMIT 1");
$num_new_pm = mysql_num_rows($sql_pm_check);
if ($num_new_pm > 0) {
    $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="images/pm2.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
} else {
    $PM_envelope = '<a href="pm_inbox.php"><img src="images/pm1.gif" width="18" height="11" alt="PM" border="0"/></a>';
}
// Ready the output for this logged in user
 $logOptions = $PM_envelope . ' &nbsp; &nbsp;
 <!--<a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '">Home</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; -->
 <a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/profile.php?id=' . $logOptions_id . '">Profile</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="dc">
<a href="#" onclick="return false">Account &nbsp; <img src="../images/darr.gif" width="10" height="5" alt="Account Options" border="0"/></a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/edit_profile.php">Account Options</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_inbox.php">Inbox Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/pm_sentbox.php">Sent Messages</a></li>
<li><a href="http://' . $dyn_www . '/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>';
}


?>
```

i thought i could possibly add something along the lines of

`// set profile type depending on which user type it is
    if ($accounttype == "a") {
        $userOptions = "";
    } else if ($accounttype == "b") {
        $userOptions = "";
    } else if ($accounttype == "c") {
        $userOptions = "";
    } else if ($accounttype == "d") {
        $userOptions = "";
    } else if ($accounttype == "e") {
        $userOptions = "";
    } else if ($accounttype == "f") {
        $userOptions = "";

    } else {
       $userOptions = "";
    }`

but really unsure as i would also need to changed the edit profile page aswell

sorry if im unclear about what im trying to achieve just say and ill try to clarify but any help here would be great, i know its going to be if and else statements and a call to mysql think i hit a blank spot in my head

Comment: What in the world are `$id_array = explode("nm2c0c4y3dn3727553", $decryptedID);` and the similar lines supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use something like:

You build the array:

```
$accountType = array('a', 'b');
$userOptions = array();
```

Than

```
foreach ($accountType as $value)
{
     switch ($value)
     {
         case $value:
           $userOptions[] = 'option '.$value;
         break;
     }
}

print_r($userOptions);
```

this is a very efficient way of symplifing your code and make it more dynamic.

Comment: then i just list out my links in useroptions betwen the brackets?

Comment: that depends on you, it's your decision how you want to organize it

Answer (score 0):

This is the WebIntersect code, isn't it?

Change this line:

```
header("location: index.php");
```

to

```
header("location: profile.php?=". $userID ."");
```

It's line 86 in the original changeuserlog.php.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey michael, i actually came away from the webintersect code. although its a really good tutorial and a good starting point, i felt it cornered you in a few places and adding the functions i wanted meant having to change a lot of adams code.

Comment: i have used some of the examples he showed but i have completely written my own php and found a way to do exactly what i needed, although it might not be the cleanest code, it does exactly what i need and ill pay someone after to clean it up lol